# Remove Everything Between Two Characters As Long As They Aren't Inside Some Other Characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Basically, my goal is to remove everything inside ()'s except for strings that are inside "".

I was following the code here:  [Remove text in-between delimiters in a string (using a regex?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359412/c-remove-text-in-between-delimiters-in-a-string-regex)

And that works great; but I have the additional requirement of not removing ()s if they are in "".  Is that something that can be done with a regular expression.  I feel like I'm dangerously close to needing another approach like a true parser.

This is the what I've been using....

```
string RemoveBetween(string s, char begin, char end)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(string.Format("\\{0}.*?\\{1}", begin, end));
    return regex.Replace(s, string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Is there also a requirement that the user can insert a double-quote within the double-quotes using an escape character?  ("The dog said \"Woof\"")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET regexes are even more powerful than the usual and you can surely do what you want.  Take a look at this, which looks for balanced parentheses, which is essentially the same problem as yours but with parentheses and not quotes.

http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396452.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I don't speak C, but here's the java implementation:

```
input.replaceAll("(?<=\\().*?(?=[\"()])(\"([^\"]*)\")?.*(?=\\))", "$2");
```

This produces the following results:

```
"foo (bar \"hello world\" foo) bar" --> "foo (hello world) bar"
"foo (bar foo) bar" --> "foo () bar"
```

It wasn't clear whether you wanted to preserve the quotes - if you did, use $1 instead of $2

Now that you've got the working regex, you should be able to make it work for you in C.

Comment: This doesn't work in the .NET implementation. I tried it here: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Comment: @Andrew - there's got to be a way to make it work somehow - surely even .NET has industry standard regex handing?

Comment: Just one +1 for that awesome regex... *cry*

Answer (score 2):

It's risky to say "No you can't" on this forum, because somebody will go and ruin it by providing a working answer. :-)

But I will say that this would be really stretching regular expressions, and your problem elegantly lends itself to [Automata-based programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata-based_programming).

Personally, I'm happier maintaining a 20-line finite state machine then a 10 character regular expression.

Comment: @Bohemian - I feel vindicated on two counts 1) Somebody did provide an answer 2) I'd still prefer twenty lines of FSA code  :-)