# string trim remove space?

Tags: c#, string, trim

How can I remove empty space between " " ?. 
I have more than 100 lines of rich text box and my sentence goes like below with empty space between " ".

***my sentence***

```
remove only " railing" spaces of a string in Java
remove only " trailing" spaces of a string in Java
remove only " ling" spaces of a string in Java
remove only " ing" spaces of a string in Java
.
.
.
```

***should be:***

```
remove only "railing" spaces of a string in Java
remove only "trailing" spaces of a string in Java
remove only "ling" spaces of a string in Java
remove only "ing" spaces of a string in Java
.
.
.
```

***My code***

```
richTextBox1.lines.Trim().Replace("\"  \" ", " ");
```

Comment: You should assign it back to the richTextBox1 like `richTextBox1 = richTextBox1.lines.Trim()`

Answer (score 1):

Using regex:

```
string RemoveBetween(string s, char begin, char end)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(string.Format("\\{0}.*?\\{1}", begin, end));
    return regex.Replace(s, string.Empty);
}

string s = "remove only \"railing\" spaces of a string in Java";
s = RemoveBetween(s, '"', '"');
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1359521/1714342

You can define between which characters you wish to remove string. Read more about [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx)

EDIT:

missunderstood, you are just missing assign in richTextBox1.lines.Trim().Replace("\"  \" ", " ");

make it:

```
richTextBox1.lines = richTextBox1.lines.Trim().Replace("\"  \" ", " ");
```

Replace is not changing string.

Comment: my sentence may change but only error is space that between " " so how can I make your code generic. not only string s

Comment: got this error:  'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Trim' and no extension method 'Trim' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the reassign to richTextBox1. Replace() returns string value with correct text.
Your code should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Count(); i++)
{
    richTextBox1.Lines[i] = richTextBox1.Lines[i].Trim().Replace("\" \" ", " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
richTextBox1 = richTextBox1.lines.Trim().Replace(" \" ", " \"");
```