# Remove a defined part from a string

Tags: c#, string, char

Lets say I have this string:

```
string text = "Hi my name is <crazy> Bob";
```

I want to take away everything within the brackets so it turns out like this:

```
"Hi my name is Bob".
```

So for I've tried with this and I know I've been think wrong with the while-loop but I just can't figure it out.

```
    public static string Remove(string text)
    {
        char[] result = new char[text.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++ )
        {
            if (text[i] == '<')
            {
                while (text[i] != '>')
                {
                    result[i] += text[i];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result[i] += text[i];
            }
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: look for regular expressions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359412/c-sharp-remove-text-in-between-delimiters-in-a-string-regex

Comment: Can the input be `Hi my name is <crazy> uncle <strange> Bob.`? Should it remove only `crazy` and `strange` or `uncle` as well?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359412/c-sharp-remove-text-in-between-delimiters-in-a-string-regex ?

Comment: Change `result[i] += text[i];` inside `while(text[i]!='>')` loop to `i++;` to be able to pass through characters inside `'<''>'` and return `new string(result);`

Answer (score 11):

Try this Regex:

```
public static string Remove(string text)
{
    return  Regex.Replace(text, "<.*?>","");
}
```

Comment: dang... my typing is not quick enough!

Comment: dammit - beat me to it by like 2 seconds!

Comment: This is a great alternative but it doesn't help the OP understand why their attempted solution doesn't work.

Comment: @DaveParsons Though you're right, I don't even bother to look at what's wrong when you can achieve it easily. Basically am lazy :-D

Answer (score 6):

Look at this loop:

```
while (text[i] != '>')
{
    result[i] += text[i];
}
```

That will continue executing until the condition isn't met. Given that you're not changing `text[i]`, it's never going to stop...

Additionally, you're calling `ToString` on a `char[]` which isn't going to do what you want, and even if it did you'd have left-over characters.

If you wanted to loop like this, I'd use a `StringBuilder`, and just keep track of whether you're "in" an angle bracket or not:

```
public static string RemoveAngleBracketedContent(string text)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    int depth = 0;
    foreach (var character in text)
    {
        if (character == '<')
        {
            depth++;
        }
        else if (character == '>' && depth > 0)
        {
            depth--;
        }
        else if (depth == 0)
        {
            builder.Append(character);
        }
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Alternatively, use a regular expression. It would be relatively tricky to get it to cope with nested angle brackets, but if you don't need that, it's really simple:

```
// You can reuse this every time
private static Regex AngleBracketPattern = new Regex("<[^>]*>");
...

text = AngleBracketPattern.Replace(text, "");
```

One last problem though - after removing the angle-bracketed-text from `"Hi my name is <crazy> Bob"` you actually get `"Hi my name is  Bob"` - note the double space.

Comment: +1 For giving the OP both the proverbial fishing lesson and a fish!

Answer (score 2):

use

```
string text = "Hi my name is <crazy> Bob";
text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, "<.*?>",string.Empty);
```

Comment: the answer is same as @Sriram Sakthivel answer

Answer (score 0):

I recommend regex.

```
public static string DoIt(string content, string from, string to)
{
    string regex = $"(\\{from})(.*)(\\{to})";
    return Regex.Replace(content, regex, "");
}
```