# hi i want the substring of a string in @html.displayfor(modelItem=>item.resumelink)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, substring, display, displayfor

hi guys i am new to mvc and i am working on one project...where in my view i need to get a substring of a string in `@html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.resumelink).`

i tried couple of things like

```
    <span>
        @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.ResumeLink,new {text=item.ResumeLink.Contains("#") ? item.ResumeLink.Substring(0, item.ResumeLink.IndexOf("#")) : item.ResumeLink })
    </span>
```

but it is not working.

i am trying to create display template but i dont know how to get the last index of a file till where i want to crop my string...any help would be appreciated..thnks

Comment: PLease show the string and the substring which you want to get from string

Comment: Do u want to display the substring to the user ?

Comment: ok i got rid of the thing i wanted but still something is missing...i declared one more porperty in a class that will get a substring of a prev property

public string ResumeSubString
        {
            get
            {
                return ResumeLink.Contains("#") ? ResumeLink.Substring(0, ResumeLink.IndexOf("#")) : ResumeLink;
            }
        }

but that removes extension of a file also...but i need to display extention of a file just by removing guid after filename

Comment: like i have file name

 about us#fb40c127-9501-40ad-807c-9b8216348005.docx

but i want to show  about us.docx...by only removing #fb40c127-9501-40ad-807c-9b8216348005 from a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep the code clean this way, the idea used here is.. find the index of `#`
then find the index of `.` and remove all the characters in this index range.

```
<span>
     @{
        var filename = item.ResumeLink; 
        var actualFileName = filename.Contains("#") ? file.Remove(file.IndexOf('#'), (file.IndexOf('.') - file.IndexOf('#'))) : filename ; 
      }
     @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.ResumeLink,new {text= @actualFileName })
  </span>
```

Result 
if `item.ResumeLink = us#fb40c127-9501-40ad-807c-9b8216348005.docx`

```
"us.docx"
```

Comment: it gives a following error 

Index and count must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: count

Comment: From which line of code?? Are you sure its from this code itself??

Comment: yes from this line

var actualFileName = filename.Contains("#") ? filename.Remove(filename.IndexOf('#'), filename.IndexOf('.')- 2) : filename;

Comment: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and count must refer to a location within the string.

Comment: I actually tested this code and then gave you the answer. Can you tell me what is the value of `item.ResumeLink` when you get this error

Comment: item.ResumeLink = "index page#b07a334c-3db1-4b36-8185-bc1e5e3f99e9.doc" when i debug..then on the next line it thorws exception like i said

Comment: Also I prefer using regex to remove the substring. It would be much simpler and neat that way.

Comment: thnx bro......although LableFor doesnt display filename...so i apply this function in my class declaring property in which i am passing another property values then picking a substring to remove...thank you i appreciate foir your help , effort and time :)

Comment: @KaranTrivedi glad to help brother !!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ActionLink(modelItem => item.ResumeLink, modelItem => item.ResumeLink, new {text=modelItem => item.ResumeLink.Substring(0,2) })
```

This will generate a url like this

```
Controller/action/text=20    // i cut the value of 2014
```

Comment: that will just display ResumeLink to the user for a LableFor methor...so i am using DisplayFor insted of LabelFor....and i created a property which will give substring of a another propery.

Comment: do u want the text value to be available in another action method ??

Comment: the displayfor or the  labelfor overloads stores the values as html attributes , if you want the user to click on the link and get the value there by redirecting him to different action method use should use the @html.ActionLink helper

Comment: yes but i did try 
@Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.ResumeLink,new {text=item.ResumeLink.Contains("#") ? item.ResumeLink.Substring(0, item.ResumeLink.IndexOf("#")) : item.ResumeLink })

but it doesnt work...so what i did is creaTED A ANOTHER PROPERTY IN A MODEL CLASS
        public string ResumeLink { get; set; }
        public string ResumeSubString
        {
            get
            {
                return ResumeLink.Contains("#") ? ResumeLink.Substring(0, ResumeLink.IndexOf("#")) : ResumeLink;
            }
and in a view file@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.ResumeSubString)

Comment: i think this should work
@Html.ActionLink(modelItem => item.ResumeLink, modelItem => item.ResumeLink, new {text=modelItem => item.ResumeLink.Substring(0,2) })

Comment: can u just tell if i have a string : about us#fb40c127-9501-40ad-807c-9b8216348005.docx

and i just need a substring as: about us.docx 

by removing: #fb40c127-9501-40ad-807c-9b8216348005 from the origional string

so how to get it...m confused with indexOF parameters as i am a noob in this

Comment: you should use 
text.TrimStart('#') if you are sure about what is the ending characters , else you have to use Regex

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359412/c-sharp-remove-text-in-between-delimiters-in-a-string-regex

Answer (score 0):

in a view i write ` 
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ResumeSubString)

```
       @*<a href="#" /> <span>@Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.ResumeLink,new {text=item.ResumeLink.Contains("#") ? item.ResumeLink.Substring(0, item.ResumeLink.IndexOf("#")) : item.ResumeLink })</span>*@
    </td>`
```

and in a class there is something like following

```
public string ResumeLink { get; set; }
    public string ResumeSubString
    {

        get
        {
            var filename = ResumeLink;
            var actualFileName = filename.Contains("#") ? filename.Remove(filename.IndexOf('#'), (filename.IndexOf('.') - filename.IndexOf('#'))) : filename;
            return actualFileName;
        }
    }
```

thnx reddy and guys whoever bother to reply :)