# Regular Expressions to remove repeated Text pattern from string

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to remove a repeated pattern or text using regex.  The input text is:

> RuleSet:[text], Data:[{text}{text}...] RuleSet:[text], Data:[{text},{text},....] SomeText RuleSet:[{text}...], Data:[{text}...]

Where substring can be any alphanumeric word and can contain special characters as well spaces.  I am trying to remove any of the following:

- `RuleSet:[text],`
- `Data:[{text}{text}...]`

I'd like to retain the following `SomeText`

I have tried many ways of doing it, but I can't seem to get the desired result.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: And what exactly do you mean be "special character"?

Comment: Followed the response from the stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359412/c-sharp-remove-text-in-between-delimiters-in-a-string-regex.  prepared test pattern to just remove anything with "(RuleSet\:\[.*\])" pattern. but it removes everything as it matches the end "]"

Comment: The special characters are ! & ( ) |

Comment: can you give an example input and expected output?

Comment: Thanks all, the regex below worked excellent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

```
\s?(?:RuleSet|Data):\[[^]]*](?:,?\s|$)
```

**Replace with:**  nothing

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- find substrings that look like `RuleSet:[text],` or `Data:[{text}{text}...]`
- allow you to replace these with anything, or in this case nothing

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/eJ2aB5/1

**Sample text**

> RuleSet:[text], Data:[{text}{text}...] RuleSet:[text], Data:[{text},{text},....] SomeText RuleSet:[{text}...], Data:[{text}...]

**After Replace**

> SomeText

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s?                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                           (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    RuleSet                  'RuleSet'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Data                     'Data'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^]]*                    any character except: ']' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ]                        ']'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ,?                       ',' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                             "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks @Ro Yo Mi, It did work for me and with better response time.  I did get the expected results using "RuleSet\:\[(\s*?.*?)*?\]\,\s|Data\:\[(\s*?.*?)*?\]|"

Comment: I don't like using `.*?` assertion when working with values with wrapped characters like brackets, parenthesis, or quotes as it tends to lead to unexpected results. But if it works for you then that's awesome.